# How forget what it learned OR How to start two different neural network?

Tags: javascript, node.js, neural-network, brain.js

I Use library brain.js. 
https://github.com/BrainJS/brain.js
I dont understand.

For example I start neural network use "data 1" and get "answer 1".
How to do forget this data and start teaching use new "data 2" for new "answer 2"?
The first, what i think, it is restart program, but how use javascript code.
Or me need ask question in github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
var net1 = new brain.NeuralNetwork();
var res1 = net1.train(arr1);

var net2 = new brain.NeuralNetwork();
var res2 = net2.train(arr2);
```

may be